# Laravel keeps creating public folder

Tags: laravel

Its getting annoying that laravel on live server keeps creating `public` folder while website is loading from `public_html` folder. It keeps upload files in public folder and everytime I run npm commands it updates assets in `public` folder instead of `public_html`

I even placed this code in `index.php` in `public_html` folder but no luck.

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

any idea how to get rid of `public` folder for good?

Comment: does it mean that you have moved out `public/*` to `public_html`?

Comment: yes, that's the place my domain root will load

Comment: try placing this code in `AppServiceProvider` `register` method. `$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });`

Comment: put the code in AppProvider

Comment: You said uploaded files, **if** you meant uploaded via the application, perhaps you are using public disc to store files and the default link for public disc is `public/storage`, which you can override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `webpack.mix.js` file and do the following:

You will see:

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Change it to:

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css').setPublicPath('public_html');
```

This will make sure everytime you update assets they will be updated in the `public_html` directory.